# how to let codes runs only one time

Tags: php, session, cookies

how to let codes runs only one time.
I am developing a zencart website, I want to let php update the site setting infos when user first time open my site ,but not run these codes after that. how to do it?

```
<?php 

    //how to let codes runs only one time.
    //cookie and session? 
    function first_time_run(){
        //lot of code runs when user  open my site at first time in browser (such  as ie ,firefox)
        //but when it go to other page of my site or reenter my same page ,these codes will not run any more;
        //but if user reopen the browser , then enter my site ,thes codes will runs again
    }

    if($what){
        first_time_run();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please don't link to your other question if it's not related in any way.

Comment: sorry, i will not do that any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, shiplu's solution may work. However, if you only want the code run once ever (i.e. the first time the customer comes to the site, do something, then never do it again), you need to store some kind of user identifier in a database. If you only use the session, as soon as the user's session ends (he or she leaves the site, closes the browser, etc), then that session variable no longer exists. The next time that customer comes to the site, the script will run again.

You can also use a cookie that would persist after the user leaves the site, but still has limitations. Cookies have to have expirations (even if they are a year from now). When that cookie expires, that script will run again for the same customer. Additionally, a user can clear their cookies, use a different computer, etc and defeat your first_time_run check.

To conclude, the only lasting solution is to save some kind of customer identifier in a database and check that field whenever a user comes to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Use a session variable.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['NEEDRUN'])){
 // run it
 // remove the session variable.
 unset($_SESSION['NEEDRUN']);
}
```

Now this will be run only if the session variable is set.